# Dynamically looping through URL parameters

Tags: coldfusion

I'm trying to write a bit of code that will loop through URL parameters that start with the word 'layer' followed by 1,2,3, etc. For example:

```
http://example.cfm?numLayers=2&layer1=somevalue,123&layer2=someothervalue,456
```

The number of layers in the URL will be different each time.

This is my code:

```
<cfif isDefined("url.numLayers") AND url.numLayers gt 0>
    <cfset session.structLayers = structNew() />
    <cfloop index="index" from="1" to="#url.numCustom#">
        <cfset layerElement = evaluate(url.layer#index#) /><!--- This is where I'm having trouble --->
        <cfset arrLayerElement = listToArray(layerElement)>
        <structInsert(session.structLayers, arrLayerElement[1], arrLayerElement[2])]>
    </cfloop>
</cfif>
```

I'm getting an 'Invalid CFML construct error' on the line marked above. I'm not doing this right.

Comment: First, as mentioned below evaluate is unnecessary. It is also unsafe, so it should be avoided when possible. That said, you are using evaluate() incorrectly.  If you read [the documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f4d.html), it expects a *string* containing an expression to be evaluated. If you want grab the value of a variable named url.layer1, you need to pass in the *string* "url.layer1". Your code is not passing in the correct string.

Comment: Your example shows layer1 being equal to a list consisting of somevalue and 123.  Was that your intent or did you simply type it wrong?  Also, why do you need a structure?  You already have a list, cgi.querystring with all your data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might try something like the following. First, use `structKeyExists()` rather than `isDefined()`. You'll see better performance:

```
<cfset numLayers = 0 />
<cfif structKeyExists(url, "numLayers")>
    <cfset numLayers = val(url.numLayers) />
</cfif>
```

Also, you don't need to use `evaluate()` any more.

```
<cfset session.structLayers = {} /> <!--- instead of "structNew()" --->
<cfloop from="1" to="#numLayers#" index="ii">
    <cfif structKeyExists(url, "layer#ii#")> <!--- instead of evaluate --->
        <cfset arrLayerElement = listToArray(url["layer#ii#"]) />
        <cfset structInsert(session.structLayers, arrLayerElement[1], arrLayerElement[2]) />
    </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

---

You could also do something like this:

```
<cfloop collection="#url#" item="mylayer">
    <cfif REFindNoCase("^layer\d+$", mylayer) AND listLen(url.mylayer) EQ 2>
        <cfset structInsert(session.structLayers, listFirst(url.mylayer), listLast(url.mylayer) />
    </cfif>
 </cfloop>
```

I realized when writing this bit of code that the call to `listToArray()` is not really needed. If you were going to use the array again outside the loop then I would be all for it, but since you're using it once and then never referring to it again it's probably not worth the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the array accessor syntax (square brackets) to work with dynamic keys in a struct:

```
<cfif structKeyExists(url,"numLayers") AND url.numLayers gt 0>
    <cfset session.structLayers = {} />
    <cfloop index="index" from="1" to="#url.numCustom#">
        <!--- use this instead of evaluate to get dynamic keys out of a struct --->
        <cfset var layerElement = url["layer#index#"] />
        <!--- same way to set a dynamic key into a struct --->
        <cfset session.structLayers[listFirst(layerElement)] = listLast(layerElement) />
    </cfloop>
</cfif>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this simple code. Just replace the session_struct with your own struct. You can append this URL for testing:

```
?numLayers=5&layer1=Layer1Key,Layer1Value&layer2=Layer2Key,Layer2Value
```

```
<cfif StructKeyExists(url, "numLayers") and url.numLayers gt 0>
    <cfloop list="#StructKeyList(url)#" index="key">
        <cfif ReFindNoCase("^layer", key)>
            <cfset StructInsert(session_struct, ListGetAt(url[key], 1), ListGetAt(url[key], 2))>
        </cfif>
    </cfloop>
</cfif>

<cfdump var="#session_struct#">
```